# Understading the Big-oh notation

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

My professor says that we use $f(x) = O(g(x))$ to mean that $g(x)$ is negligible compared to $f(x)$. Im kind of confused here. The definition I found online is

$$ f(x) = O(g(x)) \iff \exists  C >0, \; \; st \; |f(x)| < C |g(x)| \; as \; x \to 0$$

With this definition I can see that for example $x < e^x $ for $x \to 0$ and so $x = O(e^x)$ how is $e^x$ negligible compared to $x$? Am I misunderstanding the concept completely?

Comment: Note that the definition of big-oh notation may have $x \to \infty$ or $x$ tending to some other limit, not necessarily zero. Regarding your question, I believe your professor misspoke; even if he/she used the more reasonable direction ("$f(x)$ is negligible compared to $g(x)$") it is not really something meant to be interpreted precisely, and is primarily to give you intuition. If you have any doubts, always go back to the definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I would use the word "negligible" for Little-Oh. The way I like to think of it is
$$f(x)=O(g(x)) \Leftrightarrow \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}<\infty$$
and
$$f(x)=o(g(x)) \Leftrightarrow \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$$
So Big-Oh means "$f$ doesn't grow too much bigger than $g$" and Little-Oh means "$f$ becomes negligible compared to $g$"

Comment: So for example sin x doesnt grow too much bigger than x because sinx / x goes to 0 but sin x / x^2 goes to infinity so x^2 doesnt grow too much bigger than sin x right ?

Comment: @Neymar not quite. $\sin{x}=o(x)$ and $\sin{x}=o(x^{2})$ because both limits go to $0$. This is because $\sin$ is always between $-1$ and $1$ but $x$ and $x^{2}$ (and in fact, any positive power of $x$) grow without bound as $x\to\infty$

Comment: @Neymar I'll also mention that if $f(x)=o(g(x))$ then necessarily $f(x)=O(g(x))$, so the cases are not always disjoint. However we can certainly have $f(x)=O(g(x))$ without having $f(x)=o(g(x))$

Comment: But sinx is big oh of x though

Comment: @Neymar Yes, it's also little oh of $x$. I suggest re-reading my other comments a bit more closely